# Installing ChildBrowser 5.0.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova, childbrowser

I'm just wondering how to install ChildBrowser on PhoneGap 3.3.0 (Build)... ChildBrowser was updated last week to support the latest PhoneGap but I don't know how to install it. I previously had it working with PhoneGap 2.3.0 but I'm starting fresh with 3.3.0. Using Terminal I've tried running this:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser
```

I have to delete the `com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser` folder each time beforehand to make sure it doesn't skip downloading any files. When I run that `plugin add` command, it tells me this:

```
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 3.3.0, failed version requirement: <=2.9.0
```

...Which makes sense because the plugin.xml file has that stipulation ([here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser/blob/master/plugin.xml), line 17), but [according to this post, ChildBrowser now supports PhoneGap 3.3.0](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/childbrowser_plugin_now_supported_by_phonegap_3_3_0). The plugin.xml file was updated 6 or 7 days ago, around the same time as that post, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser#f4d5ef2ed6f35da0af8a819f30edcd53e6877770
```

UPDATE: I just tested again with the above command. It still works. I am very new to git so I might be wrong in this explanation... I found that the most updated version of this plugin is not the master branch. Then I proceeded to get the "hash" (or tag?) of the most updated branch from the url of github (which is "f4d5ef2ed6f35da0af8a819f30edcd53e6877770"). Because I wanted to download that particular version for my local build. After digging from the internet, I found that I could put append "#f4d5ef2ed6f35da0af8a819f30edcd53e6877770" (note: with that "#" in the beginning) in the url for the command. Then it worked.

If someone tries to build it with phonegap's cloud service, it's okay to just include this tag in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser" />
```

which you can find in [the docs](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/480).

Comment: This works, and if it doesn't for anyone else reading this, the solution (at the moment - will probably not be necessary soon) is to run the plugin add that was in my question, then download right from https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser#f4d5ef2ed6f35da0af8a819f30edcd53e6877770 page... take the contents of that version and overwrite the files in whatever folder the original command had created. Then run the command that was in the question again.

Comment: This link no longer works - also fails to install the Android version on Cordova 3.3.0

Comment: @JoughDempsey I just tried and it still works... What I would suggest is to remove everything under /plugins, /merges and /platforms. Then install the plugins locally agian and build again. Hope this helps.